# PHP Table by Column from Non Sequential Rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been struggling for a few months now with coming up with an acceptable code for creating a table. What I have now works but I know it is not the proper way to do it.

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a table with nine columns and six rows. Each column needs to pull from a different "class" within my database which I've linked as an image of below.

The first cell would pull the first "Facilities" class entry the second cell would pull the first "Star-Line" class entry and so on with "RoHS" rounding out the first row. The second row's first cell would pull the second entry under the "Facilities" class and the second entry from the "Star-Line" class and so on with "RoHS" rounding out the second row. This would continue on for six rows until the table would be complete.

What I've done to jerry-rig this table is to create a table column called "class_id" and have it go in increments of nine with blank fields for the rows that don't have 6 entries. You can see this table below which looks correct but I know I did not get there the correct way.

In my perfect world I would like to have a minimalist database like I do now, without any blank entries, and the ability to pull by "class" and for that data to go in the proper cell.

I have other databases I would like to do this with and would appreciate help in finally solving this issue.

[image: Mysql Data Base]

[image: Proper Looking Table]

```
<?

$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
$dbCon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbName, $username, $password, $attrs);
$dbCon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


?>

<div style='border-bottom: 1px dashed #0083ca; height: 150px;'>
    <p><img style='float: left;' alt='Quality' src='/images/quality/images/certified.jpg' height='146' width='200' />Amphenol Industrial Products Group prides itself on producing the highest quality connectors in the world. We aim to 'Delight Our Customers' by supplying reliable, world class interconnect products. Our Quality Assurance systems ensure consistent processes across all of our facilities around the globe. Our list of certifications can be found within this page.</p>
</div><br>

<?

echo "<table id='qTable'>".PHP_EOL;
echo "<thead>".PHP_EOL;
echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
    $headsql = "SELECT * FROM head";
    $hstmt = $dbCon->prepare($headsql);
    $hstmt->execute();

while ($headrow = $hstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

if ($headrow[trackeventCat] == 'RoHS') {
    echo "<th><strong>$headrow[trackeventCat]</strong></th>".PHP_EOL; //Title   
    }

    else {  
    echo "<th><a href='$headrow[link]' target='_blank'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '<? echo "$headrow[trackeventType]"?>', 'Quality', '<?php echo "$headrow[trackeventFile]"?>']);"><? echo "<strong>$headrow[trackeventCat]</strong></a></th>".PHP_EOL; //Title
    }
}
echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
echo "</thead>".PHP_EOL;    

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM certs ORDER BY class_id, id";
    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

$nRows = $dbCon->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM certs')->fetchColumn(); 
$cntr = 0;

echo "<tbody>".PHP_EOL;
echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

 $cntr++;


if ($row[text] == 'IP68-8' && $row['class'] == 'Star-Line') {
    echo "<td><a href='/$row[file]' target='_blank'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Quality', '<?php                            
        echo "$row[text] | $row[class]"?>']);"><? echo "$row[text]</a></td>".PHP_EOL;
}
    elseif (substr($row[text],0,2) == 'IP') {
        echo "<td>$row[text]</td>".PHP_EOL;
}
    elseif ($row[text] == "") {echo "<td>".PHP_EOL; echo "</td>".PHP_EOL;
}

    else {       

        echo "<td><a href='/$row[file]' target='_blank'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Quality', '<?php                            
        echo "$row[text] | $row[class]"?>']);"><? echo "$row[text]</a></td>".PHP_EOL;
}

    if ($cntr % $nRows == 0) {echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL;}
     elseif ($cntr % 9 == 0) {
      echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL; echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;}
}
echo "</tbody>".PHP_EOL;
echo "</table>".PHP_EOL; 
$dbCon = null;
?>
```

Comment: Gather the data in an array first. Then you can loop over that array for each table cell, and only output the element that belongs into the current cell.

Comment: I had a feeling an array would play into it but I am not a programmer and will need some guidance if anyone is willing.

Comment: Now change your password.

Answer (score 1):

Why not structure your database like what you show in your output table, where each row/record has nine "properties" (which may or may not have data populated into them).

That would perhaps make your DB table have fields like:

```
id
facilities
star_line
star_line_ex
amphe_ex
... etc.
```

In this way your table better models the "real world" records that you are trying to work with.

This would also GREATLY simplify the process of reading the DB table date our into individual records.

Comment: I've actually tried that before and it does work but I end up with 28 columns across in the data base and that just did not seem efficient to me. If this is the way it's done I can accept that and move on I just thought it strange to have so many columns.

Comment: @Hartman9 Based on your example, there would only be 10 columns (id + 9 different fields).  If you truly have 28 properties per record, I don't see a problem with that.  You might need to ask yourself though if perhaps all of those are truly properties of the "real world" object being represented in the table, or things that should be normalized out into other tables. In general, the better job you do of applying a "real world" approach to modeling your data, the more likely you are to end up with a well normalized data structure with appropriate relationships between tables.

Comment: Mike I see where you are going with your suggestion. I still think I would need an additional nine columns for a total of 19 because of the URL "file" fields.  Because Facilities would need it's own file column and Star-Line would and so on.  Does this sound right?

Comment: @Hartman9 Yes perhaps you would in this case.  If however you might have multiple records with the same Star-line or other files (i.e. not always a 1-to-1 relation) then perhaps the file paths go into a separate file table with just the id from that table being referenced in this main table such that you build the relation between this table and the file table, reducing duplicate entries in the main table. This is why I am stressing thinking about the "real world" relationships amongst the items you are modelling in your system.